# django customize reset password form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, recaptcha, reset-password

I am a beginner in django (django 1.7 python 2.7).

I am trying to add [no captcha recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) onto my django reset password form.

I am trying to use this [recaptcha djano plugin](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha).

I have followed the instructions and added the necessay settings:

`Installed django-recaptcha to the Python path.`

`Added captcha to the INSTALLED_APPS setting.`

Added the following to my settings.py file:

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '76wtgdfsjhsydt7r5FFGFhgsdfytd656sad75fgh' # fake - for the purpose of this post.
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '98dfg6df7g56df6gdfgdfg65JHJH656565GFGFGs' # fake - for the purpose of this post.
NOCAPTCHA = True
```

The instructions then advise to add the captcha to the form, like so:

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class FormWithCaptcha(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

**How do I access the built in reset password form? As a beginner, I suspect that I have to customise the built in reset password form, but how do I do that? I am not even sure where the built in reset password form is.** An example of how to customise the build in reset password form or a push to a tutorial would be handy.

I have searched SO & google, but could not find anything suitable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to customise the [`PasswordReset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) view. By default, it uses the [`PasswordResetForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm), which you can customize.

```
# in e.g. myapp/forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class CaptchaPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    ...
```

Then in your `urls.py`, import your form, and use the `form_class` to specify the form.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from web.forms import CaptchaPasswordResetForm

urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts/password_reset/", auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=CaptchaPasswordResetForm)),
]
```

For Django < 1.11, you need to customise the URL pattern for the `password_reset` view, and set `password_reset_form` to

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from myapp.forms import CaptchaPasswordResetForm

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(
        r'^password_reset/',
        auth_views.password_reset,
        {'password_reset_form': CaptchaPasswordResetForm},
    )
]
```

For more information about including password reset views in your urls, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).

Comment: Alasdair, thanks for the code. I changed some of the code, but you definately pushed me over the finish line.

Comment: Glad you got it working! If there's any mistakes in the code, you can suggest an edit to help future visitors.

Comment: Alasdir, no mistakes in code, just changed it for my form/url etc. environment. Thanks again.