# Its Posible to add more fields in django password reset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Can I add more fields to django password reset forms?
For example, username fields: then if username and email is valid, the password reset link will be sent to email.
Please help me, I want to password reset like this photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yElGM.png)

Comment: yes , why not. control is totally up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The form can be customized as you wish.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604481/django-customize-reset-password-form) question.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Customize the PasswordResetForm. To add username in PasswordResetForm customize as below.

**add the mentioned code to customize to you needs.**
look at **#add this**  tags in code

```
import unicodedata
#add this UsernameField

class UsernameField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", super().to_python(value))

    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        return {
            **super().widget_attrs(widget),
            "autocapitalize": "none",
            "autocomplete": "username",
        }

class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    #add this
    username = UsernameField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"autofocus": True})
    )              
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "email"}),
    )
   ...
   #code as in PasswordResetForm
   ....
   
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]   #add this
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()
        for user in self.get_users(email):
            if user.username == username:    #add this
                user_email = getattr(user, email_field_name)
                context = {
                    "email": user_email,
                    "domain": domain,
                    "site_name": site_name,
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    "user": user,
                    "token": token_generator.make_token(user),
                    "protocol": "https" if use_https else "http",
                    **(extra_email_context or {}),
                }
                self.send_mail(
                    subject_template_name,
                    email_template_name,
                    context,
                    from_email,
                    user_email,
                    html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
                )
```