# Customize Django Admin user password change form

Tags: django, admin

I've customized my user model by using AbstractBaseUser.

Everything works fine, but when I am in the Django Admin interface and us the form to change a user's password, in addition to the `new password 1` and `new password 2` fields, I also see their email in a text box:

[image]

How can I remove their email address from appearing in my admin change password form? Is there a special Django form that I can subclass?

Comment: Your image is not visible. Please correct that.

Comment: You cant see it at all or it's small?

Comment: No, there is a problem with the image.

Comment: OK, i uploaded a new image. I can see it on all browsers + incognito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding username as a hidden field fixed this for me.

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['username']
```

I was using the email as a username.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to customize the [password_reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) view.
Please, read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).

If you want go further, you can override the `PasswordResetForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class FooPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    ...
```

Then update your URL and do not forgot to pass your form to the `password_reset_form` argument:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from myapp.forms import FooPasswordResetForm

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(
        '^password_reset/',
        auth_views.password_reset,
        {'password_reset_form': FooPasswordResetForm},
    )
]
```

Please, take also a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604481/django-customize-reset-password-form)
My answer is inspired of this question's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify I'm talking about in the admin panel so at a url that looks like www.example.com/admin/myapp/user/1/password/ . I already have a password reset view that users can use.

Comment: Did u figure out how to solve this @bones225 ? I have a problem similar to this one

Comment: @gbrennon Unfortunately I'm not working on that project anymore -- I don't believe I ever solved it. A couple tips though: 1. Use AbstractUser -- NOT AbstractBaseUser if you haven't already locked in! 2. See what you can do to overwrite the field to make the email read only.